# How to do if-else inside list eval expression?

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to perform an if-else transformation for elements in a List series. I use pl.when inside list.eval but encounter a warning message.

I have an DataFrame containing a List series, in which the lengths of each row are different:

```py
In [2]: df = pl.DataFrame({"Tokens": [["a", "b", "c"], ["a"], ["unknown"]]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ Tokens          │
│ ---             │
│ list[str]       │
╞═════════════════╡
│ ["a", "b", "c"] │
│ ["a"]           │
│ ["unknown"]     │
└─────────────────┘
```

Now I want to perform a if-else transformation on each elements in the List series. More specifically: `lambda token: -1 if token == 'unknown' else hash(token)`

I try to use pl.when inside list.eval expression. It works but raises such warning: `The predicate '[(col("")) == (Utf8(__ANY__))]' in 'when->then->otherwise' is not a valid aggregation and might produce a different number of rows than the group_by operation would. This behavior is experimental and may be subject to change`

```py
In [12]: df.with_columns(pl.col("Tokens").list.eval(pl.when(pl.element() == 'unknown').then(pl.lit(0, dtype=pl.UInt64)).otherwise(pl.element().hash())))
The predicate '[(col("")) == (Utf8(unknown))]' in 'when->then->otherwise' is not a valid aggregation and might produce a different number of rows than the groupby operation would. This behavior is experimental and may be subject to change
Out[12]:
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ Tokens                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[u64]                         │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [1588745937650624681, 1558575890… │
│ [1588745937650624681]             │
│ [0]                               │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: The warning is a bug. It is fixed on main and will be part of the next release. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10055

Answer (score 2):

## Conditionals in polars

### Per the [docs](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/functions/#conditionals), use the `pl.when`, `then`, `otherwise` syntax.

(See also: **[Column assignment based on predicate](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/migration/pandas/#column-assignment)**.)

```py
import polars as pl
  
print(f"Polars version: {pl.__version__}\n") # NOTE: See polars docs.＊

df = pl.DataFrame({"Tokens": [["a", "b", "c"], ["a"], ["unknown"]]})
print(df)

transform_expr = (
    pl.when(pl.element() == "unknown")
    .then(pl.lit(-1))
    .otherwise(pl.element().hash())
)

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Tokens").list.eval(transform_expr).alias("Tokens")
)

print(df)
```

gives:

```
Polars version: 0.20.13

shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ Tokens          │
│ ---             │
│ list[str]       │
╞═════════════════╡
│ ["a", "b", "c"] │
│ ["a"]           │
│ ["unknown"]     │
└─────────────────┘
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ Tokens                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[f64]                         │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [8.1448e17, 6.3145e15, 1.8296e19… │
│ [8.1448e17]                       │
│ [-1.0]                            │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

<sub><sup>＊</sup>[`polars.Expr.hash`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.hash.html): Hash values returned not guaranteed stable except within same version of polars.</sub>